# How can we add multiple user inputs in a single prompt (in javascript)?

Tags: javascript

I want to take multiple user inputs from user in a single prompt box. How can this be possible?

Comment: It's not possible. `prompt` is not made for that. Unless you want users to put a separator in their answer and you can split for that. But it's ugly and error-prone.

Comment: You'd need either multiple prompts, or a single prompt with a separator that the user is forced to enter. Or you could make your own custom modal.

Comment: Use a `<input>` with HTML instead. A little more work, but can be integrated with the design of the page a lot more than a prompt widget, controlled by the browser.

Comment: Anyway, why use a prompt and not a form?

Answer (score 1):

In not possible in native browser behavior.
You need use custom library for creating modal element. For example you can use `jQuery UI`

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it would be to have a common separator that you split on. For instance, for the delimiter `~`, you could do this:

```js
const inputs = prompt("Enter your inputs separated by a tilde ~").split("~");

console.log(inputs);
```

This is not a good way to obtain multiple inputs due to the fact that the user may make a mistake when entering their data. A much better way would be to make your own custom modal with multiple areas to input data, or simply do use many sequential prompts. But no, aside from this method, there's no way to get multiple user inputs in a single, browser default prompt box.

Comment: Nice Explanation.Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible by asking user to provide multiple data with delimeters e.g.
input1 input2
input1,input2

and you can describe the format in prompt box message.